Can pilot wave theory explain the evolution and measurement of electron spin?
Pilot wave theory is usually employed to "explain away" the randomness of QM in the context of the motion of particles (the double slit experiment, scattering). However, what about other, internal properties of quantum systems, like spin? How does the theory explain the results of, for example, the Stern-Gerlach experiment?
